# Cambiar yarn a npm como gestor de paquetes

Tags: vue.js, npm, cli, yarn

tengo un problema con crear un proyecto con el cli de vue.
Resulta que yo uso npm para instalar todo, y funcionaba perfectamente, pero me dio curiosidad usar yarn y lo instale, ahora que no me gusto del todo yarn lo desinstale y crei que con eso volveria a utilizar npm, pero resulta que me da este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es evidente por que desisntale yarn, pero yo quiero volver a usar npm. Pero queiro volver a usar npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes acceder al archivo `~/.vuerc`, ahí encontraras algo similar a esto:

`{
  "useTaobaoRegistry": false,
  "packageManager": "yarn"
}`

Simplemente cambia **"yarn"** por **"npm"**

`{
  "useTaobaoRegistry": false,
  "packageManager": "npm"
}`

Comment: Gracias me sirvio

Comment: De nada amigo, por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada para los demás usuarios con este problema.